# Login not functioning with converted Prepared Statements SQLi

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

As recommended, I've been trying to secure my DB by using prepared statements.  I have the following login that works perfectly that I'm trying to convert to prepared statement.

```
if(isset($_POST["Submit"])) {
$Username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["Username"]);

    $get_hash_db = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT password FROM admin_registration WHERE username='$Username'");

    $hash_db_data = mysqli_fetch_array($get_hash_db);
    $hash = $hash_db_data['password'];

    echo $hash;

    if(password_verify($_POST['Password'], $hash)){
        $Password = $hash;
    }else {
        $_SESSION["ErrorMessage"] = "Username or Password was incorrect";
    Redirect_to("admin_login.php");
    }
else {

        $Found_Account = Login_Attempt($Username, $Password); 
        $_SESSION["User_Id"] = $Found_Account["id"];
        $_SESSION["Username"] = $Found_Account["username"];
        if($Found_Account) {
            $_SESSION["SuccessMessage"] = "Login Successful! Welcome {$_SESSION["Username"]}";
            Redirect_to("blog_admin/dashboard.php");
        }else {
            $_SESSION["ErrorMessage"] = "Invalid Username / Password";
            Redirect_to("admin_login.php");
        }
    }
 }
```

Below this it takes you into a `Login_Attempt()` function that look like this:

```
function Login_Attempt($Username, $Password) {

    global $con;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM admin_registration WHERE username='$Username' AND password='$Password'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    if($admin = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        return $admin;
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

With my new prepared statements I never get past `$_SESSION["ErrorMessage"] = "Invalid Username / Password";`  Which tells me that I'm at least satisfying the condition `$Password = $hash;`  Here is what I have.

```
 if(isset($_POST["Submit"])) {
$Username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["Username"]);

$get_hash_db = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT password FROM admin_registration WHERE username = ? ");

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($get_hash_db, "s", $Username);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($get_hash_db);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($get_hash_db, $hash);
    mysqli_stmt_fetch($get_hash_db);

    echo $hash;

    if(password_verify($_POST['Password'], $hash)){
        $Password = $hash;
    }else {
        $_SESSION["ErrorMessage"] = "Username or Password was incorrect";
    Redirect_to("admin_login.php");
    }
```

Once I get passed this, I'm going through this:

```
else {

        $Found_Account = Login_Attempt($Username, $Password); 
        $_SESSION["User_Id"] = $Found_Account["id"];
        $_SESSION["Username"] = $Found_Account["username"];
        if($Found_Account) {
            $_SESSION["SuccessMessage"] = "Login Successful! Welcome {$_SESSION["Username"]}";
            Redirect_to("blog_admin/dashboard.php");
        }else {
            $_SESSION["ErrorMessage"] = "Invalid Username / Password";
            Redirect_to("admin_login.php");
        }
    }
 }
```

but it always returns to `$_SESSION["ErrorMessage"] = "Invalid Username / Password";`  I'm not sure I understand why?  Is it because I'm binding the param `$Username`, so function `Login_Attempt($Username, $Password)` does not handle correctly?  Sorry, this is my first go at prepared statements so really struggling to understand.

Comment: ot: you dont need to use real_escape_string when you use prepared statement.

Comment: I've removed the real_escape_string, but it doesn't change the result.

Comment: I dont understand how those parts of code are connected. Have a look here - quite rewrited code - https://pastebin.com/4aXsp3YE

Comment: much more clean, thankyou.  So I don't need the function `Login_Attempt()` at all then, using this method.  How would I account for the fields being empty and submitted...Like so?    `if(empty($Username) || empty ($Password)) {
 $_SESSION["ErrorMessage"] = "All Fields must be filled out";
 Redirect_to("admin_login.php");

}`

Comment: I would nest it into another if, first if with submited, if submitted, then if not empty and other validations